# How to define a solid color for background in Ubuntu 16.04 (with Cinnamon desktop)

Tags: cinnamon, desktop-background

**Environment**

Ubuntu 16.04
Cinnamon Desktop

From notes I jotted down when installing all system components a few months ago, I believe I installed Cinnamon Desktop as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:moorkai/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

When I go to `System Settings` > `Backgrounds` , there is no option to choose a solid color.

[image]

**Question**

How to define a solid color for background in Ubuntu 16.04 (with Cinnamon Desktop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer here:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/how-to-remove-background-in-cinnamon-desktop-4175556682/#post5437769

`System Settings` > `Backgrounds` > `Settings` > `Picture Aspect` > `'No Picture'`